# How do I set the Pin Title with Calendar on the Map?

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, annotations, mkannotation

I'm new to iPhone development.
I have a question that I'm puzzled for a week.
Now I already have a calendar on my view, and I'm trying to add a new view with map and annotation pin, so I want my event's title which is from the calendar to be passed to the annotation pin's title, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial) will help you, it covers custom annotations and titles.

Comment: Hmmm... Actually I want to pass the title string, but thank you for help, I'll try it.